# Retrieving UIImage from UIImageView sized accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

How may I retrieve the image from `imageView` sized as it is displayed (given the content mode), and not as it is according to native properties?

Code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WID, WID)];
imageView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y + Y_OFFSET);
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Do you want to get the image or do you want the image bounds (CGrect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the image again then save it.

```
// Image frame size
CGSize size = imageView.bounds.size;
// Grab a new CGContext
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0);
// Draw the image
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
// Grab the new image
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The above code draws the image in the frame, stretched to the bounds. If you want any other modes of how it is drawn, you have to calculate them yourself and put the desired stuff in the "Draw the image" line of code.

For example, for aspect fit, check out this algorithm:

```
- (CGRect) aspectFittedRect:(CGSize)inSize max:(CGRect)maxRect {
    float originalAspectRatio = inSize.width / inSize.height;
    float maxAspectRatio = maxRect.size.width / maxRect.size.height;

    CGRect newRect = maxRect;
    if (originalAspectRatio > maxAspectRatio) { // scale by width
        newRect.size.height = maxRect.size.height * inSize.height / inSize.width;
        newRect.origin.y += (maxRect.size.height - newRect.size.height)/2.0;
    } else {
        newRect.size.width = maxRect.size.height  * inSize.width / inSize.height;
        newRect.origin.x += (maxRect.size.width - newRect.size.width)/2.0;
    }

    return CGRectIntegral(newRect);
}
```

Just pass in `imageView.image.size` as `inSize` and `imageView.bounds` as maxRect.

Source:
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/15001-aspect-fit-algorithm.html

Comment: The image is resized with the correct aspect fit, but the size is considerably smaller than its size in `imageView`. What could be causing this?

Comment: By considerably smaller would you mean by half length and height?